# Weighted t-test for matched data R

Tags: r, statistics, matching, weighted

I used propensity score matching to match cases to controls (matchIt package, ratio 1:2). Now I want to get independent t-test statistic for age variable in both groups using weights (weights are known).

I used the same code before and it worked. It works on a sample dataset of 20 obs; doent work for 10 obs or the whole dataset (856 obs). I cant figure out what is wrong now. Type of var age is integer. 
Here is the code I use (all subjects are in the same dataset "matched_data", w = weights var):

```
wtd.t.test {weights}

wtd.t.test(matched_data$age[matched_data$group==1], 
           matched_data$age[matched_data$group==0], 
           weight=matched_data$w[matched_data$group==1], 
           weighty=matched_data$w[matched_data$group==0], samedata=FALSE)
```

and here is the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In wtd.t.test(matched_data$age[matched_data$group == 1], matched_data$age[matched_data$group ==  :
  Treating data for x and y separately

> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)
```

Sample dataset:

```
group age   w
0   25  1.911564626
1   30  1
0   72  1.911564626
1   72  1
1   72  1
0   58  0.955782313
0   83  0.955782313
0   61  0.955782313
0   71  0.955782313
0   37  0.955782313
1   77  1
1   78  1
1   65  1
0   89  0.955782313
1   50  1
1   89  1
1   63  1
0   81  0.955782313
1   65  1
0   91  0.955782313
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The warning appears only when the lengths of x and y aren't the same.

Comment: And it's not an error, only a warning. Warnings are there to let you know something might be, but is not necessarily, wrong.

Comment: thanks guys, i ended up uploading and cleaning up the dataset better and it worked..same variables, same number of observations.